# Finding a function if you know it's directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following expression
\begin{equation}
\beta \,\,\cdotp \nabla v(x,y) = - u(x,y)
\end{equation}
where $\beta \,\,\cdotp \nabla$ denotes the directional derivative of $v$ in the direction of $\beta$.

**Question:** How do I get to an explicit expression for $v$?

Intuitively I think I know what the solution should be. $v$ should be the line integral over $u(x,y)$ from $(x,y)$ to some constant point $(a,b)$, where the line along which $u$ is integrated is tangent to the vector $\beta$. In that case the directional derivative of $v$ in the direction of $\beta$ would be equal to $-u(x,y)$ because a small step in the direction of $\beta$ (or up along the line integral) would decrease the integral by $-u(x,y)$.

I don't know how to write this down though and I've looked for a lot of sources.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given data do not determine the function $(x,y)\mapsto v(x,y)$ up to an additive constant. Consider the simple example
$$v_x=u(x,y)\ ,$$
which corresponds to $\beta=(-1,0)$. In this case you might find a solution $v_0$ by "integrating $u$ with respect to $x$", but you can add an arbitrary function $y\mapsto g(y)$ to this $v_0$ and obtain another solution $v(x,y):=v_0(x,y)+g(y)$.